# getting iterator from if any()

Tags: python, iterator, any

I have this simple function:

```
keys = ['snmt1/metadata/table1/ref_table1_20190324124365.csv', 'snmt1/metadata/table2/table2_ref_20190324124365.csv', 'snmt1/metadata/table3/table3_20190324124365.csv']


def better_func(keys):
  for item in keys:
    split_key = item.split("/")
    filename = str(split_key[-1])
    prefixes = ['strm','ref','trunc']
    if any(x in filename for x in prefixes):
      location = filename.find(x)
      if location == 0:
        print True
      else:
        print "another false"
    else:
      print False
```

What I need is the value of "x" so that I can return the index of it with the .find() function. This code above doesn't work because it is telling me:

> NameError: global name 'x' is not defined

Which I understand but how can I access "x" like I can normally do in a for loop?

```
for x in my_list:
    print x
```

Comment: you want `next()` not `any()`

Comment: Could you explain a bit more. How will adding next() help me return the value of x? Any is the proper function here, it is working as expected, i just need to access the value of x to be used in .find()

Comment: `x = next((x for x in prefixes if x in filename), None):` and `if x:` (or maybe `filename.startswith(x)`-- assuming you want the first one, use a list comp for all mathces

Comment: @Chris_Rands this works except for the last iteration, then it throws an error ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 78, in <module>
    better_func(keys)
  File "main.py", line 26, in better_func
    if filename.startswith(x):
TypeError: startswith first arg must be str, unicode, or tuple, not NoneType```

Comment: I can change the value of "None" to a default value but that doesn't seem very pythonic, in order to satisfy the last iteration. That's the problem correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
if any(x in filename for x in prefixes):
    # do stuff with x
```

you can do:

```
x = next((p for p in prefixes if p in filename), None)
if x:
    # do stuff with x
```

This creates an generator, and takes the next value from it -that is, the first value.
The second argument to `None` is a sentinel value: if the iterator raises a `StopIteration`, rather than passing this exception, then `None` is returned, and bound to `x`.

This does not look so useful here, but it really comes in a handy when you want the first element of a sequence that satisfies a condition, and a fallback operation if there is no such element:

```
elt = next((x for x in range(10) if x > 5), None)
if elt is not None:
    print("{} satisfies the condition".format(elt))
else:
    print("No such element found")
```

Note that generators are iterators too, so you can directly call `next` on them. With an iterable like a list, a dict or anything else, you'd need to call `iter` first. For instance, this is useful to take an arbitrary value from a dictionary:

```
value = next(iter(d.values()))
```

Comment: `x` is just the first prefix here, not what is wanted

Comment: I tried this and it is not working as expected. It returns false for all keys

Comment: @William My bad, I fixed this

Comment: You do not need `iter`; just `next((...), None)`

Comment: you're 3rd block of code is what I ended up implementing. I originally was catching the StopIteration from the next function everytime with a "try: except:" block but then your solution of using the default value (set to None) and putting that in the if statement is more elegant

Answer (score 2):

Python 3.8 (due out late 2019) will provide assignment expressions, in part to address this exact use case of naming a witness to `any`'s success.

```
import os


def better_func(keys):
    prefixes = ['strm', 'ref', 'trunk']
    for item in keys:
        filename = os.path.basename(item)
        if any((found := x) for x in prefix if x in filename):
           if filename.startswith(found):
               print True
           else:
               print "another false"
        else:
           print False
```

Comment: Might be worth noting, that this will, technically, not assign the _first_ value of `x` that matches the condition to `found`, but _all_ values up to and including that first value, kind of like a "leaky" list comprehension. Also, `found` would take on the _last_ value of `x` if _none_ of the elements satisfy the condition.

Comment: I put the `x in filename` in the wrong place; I think it is fixed now. I'm not sure it would matter if `found` were set to previous values, though, as you can't access its value (outside of `any`, that is) until `any` itself returns.