# How can I access the value of an iterator?

Tags: python, list, split, iterator

I have been trying to split a string into different pieces in order to perform comparisons. I want to do so based on the existence of an element in *row* which is located in an initial list set at the beginning of the computer. The code is the following one, no matter what I do, it appears that the global value "Cabin" is not defined and I cannot access its value, which is the necessary one for me to make a partition on the last line

```
for row in SH_vars_dict:
            if any(Cabin in row for Cabin in Cabins):
                split_SH = row.split(Cabin+"_")
                SH_vars_dict_short.append(split_SH[1])
            else:
                SH_vars_dict_short.append(row)
                split_SH = row.split("_")

            ED_SH_thr.append(split_SH[0])
```

Is there any way to access the value of that iterator? Thanks in advance!

I performed the splits based on one particular value but then I realized that more than one value for the same array was arising on the code. Any time I try to declare this value the program reports the aforementioned error regarding the non-definition of the global name 'Cabin'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Cabin` is not global; it's a local variable in the scope of the iterator expression used as the argument for `any`.

You can use an assignment expression to capture the (first) value of `Cabin` for which `Cabin in row` is true.

```
for row in SH_vars_dict:
    if any((x := Cabin) in row for Cabin in Cabins):
        split_SH = row.split(x+"_")
        SH_vars_dict_short.append(split_SH[1])
    else:
        SH_vars_dict_short.append(row)
        split_SH = row.split("_")

    ED_SH_thr.append(split_SH[0])
```

See [PEP 572, "Scope of the target"](https://peps.python.org/pep-0572/#scope-of-the-target) for more details on how the scope of `x` is determined.

Comment: **Info**: the assignment expression (`:=`), is also known as "the walrus operator" and it was released with *Python 3.8*. https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#new-features

Comment: I personally find the name "walrus operator" silly and refuse to use it. Given that Python 3.8 is (as of last week) now the oldest supported version of Python, I consider the assignment expression something that is unconditionally available unless an older version of Python is explicitly mentioned.

Comment: @LoukasPap You can also see chepner's progress regarding that over the years, in 2019 they still said [Python 3.8 (due out late 2019) will provide assignment expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55907048) and in 2020 they still said [In Python 3.8, the assignment expression can be used](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64446395/12671057). Maybe one day they'll even close as duplicate :-P

Answer (score 0):

You could just use regular boring `for` loops:

```
for row in SH_vars_dict:
    for Cabin in Cabins:
       if Cabin in row:
           ...
```

Answer (score -2):

In Python, you can access the value of an iterator using the next() function. The next() function allows you to retrieve the next element from an iterator.
Here is an example to how to access the value of an iterator:

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
iterator = iter(numbers)

# Accessing the first value
first_value = next(iterator)
print(first_value)  # Output: 1

# Accessing the second value
second_value = next(iterator)
print(second_value)  # Output: 2

# Accessing the remaining values using a loop
for value in iterator:
    print(value)  # Output: 3, 4, 5
```

Comment: The question isn't about extracting a value from an iterator, but referring to an already extracted value outside the call to `any`.

Comment: The answer you provided is not directly relevant to the specific issue mentioned in the question. The question is about accessing the value of the Cabin variable within the context of the provided code.

Answer (score -3):

The error you're encountering is due to the scoping of variables in your code. In Python, variables defined within a loop are local to that loop and not accessible outside of it. In your case, the variable Cabin is defined within the loop, so it's not accessible in the split_SH line.

To resolve this issue, you can assign the value of Cabin to a separate variable before the loop, so that it can be accessed inside the loop. Here's an updated version of your code that should work:

Cabin_value = None  # Initialize a separate variable to hold the value of Cabin

for row in SH_vars_dict:
if any(Cabin in row for Cabin in Cabins):
Cabin_value = Cabin  # Assign the current value of Cabin to the separate variable
split_SH = row.split(Cabin_value+"*")
SH_vars_dict_short.append(split_SH[1])
else:
SH_vars_dict_short.append(row)
split_SH = row.split("*")

```
ED_SH_thr.append(split_SH[0])
```

By assigning the value of Cabin to Cabin_value before the loop, you can then use Cabin_value within the loop to perform the desired string split operation.

Comment: This answer looks like ChatGPT